# ¿Cómo retornar un arreglo en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lo que quisiera obtener es obtener la `variable` de `contador` que esta en otro `método`, pero que necesitaré usar en el `método` actual.

Código del `método` donde necesito obtener mi `variable`:

```
#region getPlanta
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getPlanta()
    {
        string resultado = "";
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        resultado = empresa.getPlanta();

        return resultado;
    }
#endregion
```

Código del `método` donde tengo mi `variable` "Contador":

```
public string getPlanta()
{
    storedProcedure sp = new storedProcedure("DBSGSIAConnectionString");
    DataTable plantas;
    plantas = new DataTable();
    string planta;
    string query = "select Top(2)* from v_DatosEmpresa;";
    plantas = sp.getValues(query);

    foreach (DataRow datos in plantas.Rows)
    {
        planta = Convert.ToString(datos[0]);
        crearHTML(planta);
    }

    return pagina+"|"+contador;
}
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta retorno el dos valores que es `pagina`, la cual no interesa ahorita y `contador` que es un `valor numérico` que requiero en el `webMethod`. En el `webMethod` retorno el valor `resultado`, pero antes de retornarlo necesito el valor de la `variable contador` para poder hacer un `ciclo for` con tantas iteraciones como tenga la variable.

### Actualización

Ya puedo obtener mi valor de la forma en que me gustaría, pero me di cuenta de que necesito que sean un conjunto de valores que no están definidos, por lo que quise usar un arreglo, pero no se como retornar un arreglo.

Código del Arreglo a retornar:

```
string[] tablas = new string[0];
Tablas tabla = new Tablas();

for (int x = 0; x < Convert.ToInt32(conteo);x++ )
{
    string query = "select * from v_Autorizaciones";
    string[] columnas = new string[] { "Certificado", "Fecha Inicio", "Fecha Fin", "Estatus" };
    string conexion = "DBSGSIAConnectionString";
    String tbl = tabla.contruirTablaContenido("tblAutorizaciones", query, columnas, conexion);
    tablas = new string[Convert.ToInt32(conteo)];
    tablas[x] = tbl;

    return Convert.ToString(tablas[x]);
}

return Convert.ToString(tablas);
```

Comment: Hola.  Por que no  diseñas una clase digamos ResultadoTablas con una propiedad Conteo y otra por ejemplo Contenido que sea un array de String? O sea public class  ResultadoTablas { public int Conteo { get; set; } public string[] Contenido { get; set; } } . No hace falta que el tipo de dato a devolver por el WebMethod sea de un tipo simple. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

He leído y releído la pregunta, y la conclusión a la que llego es que simplemente estás buscando la mejor manera de devolver 2 valores de un método. Eso explicaría la sentencia:

```
return pagina+"|"+contador;
```

En vez de tratar de devolver 2 valores de esa manera, que me parece muy frágil, yo simplemente usaría [parámetros `out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). Ejemplo:

```
public string getPlanta(out string pagina, out int contador)
{
    // código
    pagina = "abc";
    contador = 123;
}
```

Y luego puedes extraer los valores cuando haces la llamada de esta manera:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getPlanta()
{
    string resultado;
    int contador;
    Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
    empresa.getPlanta(out resultado, out contador);

    // ... puedes usar el valor de contador aquí

    return resultado;
}
```

Solo por mencionarlo, otra opción hubiera sido de devolver los 2 valores usando la clase [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx), pero tiene sus inconvenientes. Eso sí, cuando esté listo C# 7 con la mejora a los tuples, allí sí la cosa será más interesante.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas rápida de devolver varios valores (si puedes usar C# 7) sería usando un `ValueTuple`

```
public (string pagina, int contador) getPlanta()
{
    //...
    return (pagina, contador);
}
```

El tipo de dato que devuelve el método es un `ValueTuple<string, int>` y podrías luego podrías recuperar los valores de una de las siguientes maneras:

#### Usando Destructuring

```
(var pagina, var contador) = getPlanta();
```

#### Accediendo a las propiedades

```
var result = getPlanta();
var pagina = result.pagina;
var contador = result.contador;
```

#### Accediendo a las propiedades sin nombre

```
var result = getPlanta();
var pagina = result.Item1;
var contador = result.Item2;
```

Por otro lado si lo único que quieres es retornar un arreglo solo declara el arreglo como el tipo de retorno en la declaración del método

```
public string[] getPlanta()
{
    string[] paginas;
    //...

    return paginas;
}
```